# How do I call an API endpoint I created from my client-side application?

Tags: node.js, http, express, serverside-javascript

I built a server-side module that accepts a user's login and password as parameters and returns a JSON object. I am trying to call this module from my client side using the API endpoint specified in the router object but I keep getting 404 errors.

Not sure how to proceed in order to debug the issue.

My server module:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



// Endpoint to be call from the client side
router.get('/api/endpoint', function(req, res){

    let login = req.params('login')
    let pwd = req.params('pwd')

    //does stuff



  doSomething.then((value) => {
    return res.json(value)
  })
});

module.exports = myModule;
```

My client module:

```
 var MyModule = (function() {
  var endpoint = '/api/endpoint';

  // Publicly accessible methods defined
  return {

    myFunction: myFunction,

  };

    function myFunction(login, pwd) {



    // Built http request
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', endpoint, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200 && http.responseText) {
          console.log(http.responseText)
      }
    };

    // Send request
    http.send();

    }

}());
```

Ideally this function gets called with a button click, logs the user in and returns a success/failure boolean alongside the JSON object in question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only enabled `get` and not `post` for your endpoint. Try changing your `router.get` to `router.post`.

Comment: Thanks-- this helped.